# Move built dll file to specific folder by BAT script?

Tags: windows, qt, batch-file, dll, qt-creator

I am using Qt Creator to built a shared library on windows 7. Hence it generates a

myLib.dll and a myLib.lib

Is there a way such that the myLib.dll file is automatically moved, after creation, to a specific directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done automatically as post link job after a completely successful compilation according to [Qt Documentation - Variables](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html).

Add to .pro file of your project a line like:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $(COPY_FILE) "$${DESTDIR_TARGET}$${TARGET_EXT}" "C:\Destination\Directory\For Created DLL"
```

Or with following if `DESTDIR` was not defined in project before or `DESTDIR_TARGET` does not exist when *QMAKE* parses the line for creating the `MakeFile`.

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $(COPY_FILE) "$${OUT_PWD}/$${TARGET}$${TARGET_EXT}" "C:\Destination\Directory\For Created DLL"
```

And if `$${TARGET_EXT}` is replaced by an empty string, use fixed `.dll` instead of `$${TARGET_EXT}` in the line above.

It is of course also possible to **move** the DLL instead of copying it using one of the following 3 lines:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $(MOVE) "$${DESTDIR_TARGET}$${TARGET_EXT}" "C:\Destination\Directory\For Created DLL"
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $(MOVE) "$${OUT_PWD}/$${TARGET}$${TARGET_EXT}" "C:\Destination\Directory\For Created DLL"
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $(MOVE) "$${OUT_PWD}/$${TARGET}.dll" "C:\Destination\Directory\For Created DLL"
```

But on Windows there is also the *QMAKE* variable `DLLDESTDIR` to specify directly in .pro file a directory into which the created DLL should be copied after linking.

```
DLLDESTDIR="C:\Destination\Directory\For Created DLL"
```

Note: I could not testing anything written here for Windows. I can only confirm that everything written above does not work for Linux as library management is on Linux completely different in comparison to Windows.